# Put a vector inside a matrix + transformation

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix

So i have a vector created with Numpy called

```
V = [10 20 30 40  0  1]
```

And i want a matrix M like this :

```
 [10.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [20. 10.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [30. 20. 10.  0.  0.  0.]
 [40. 30. 20. 10.  0.  0.]
 [ 0. 40. 30. 20. 10.  0.]
 [ 1.  0. 40. 30. 20. 10.]
 [ 0.  1.  0. 40. 30. 20.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0. 40. 30.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0. 40.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
```

To do this i use for loops and vector extraction but it's way too long because my vector V has 500 columns and the matrix M has `500*2 -1` lines and `500` columns.

Moreover, i have to repeat this at least 100 000 times for different vector V

Is it possible, using matrix calculation and avoiding loop to get to this result ? (as fast as possible)

Thank you !

(I'm using Python 3.6 on Spyder)

EDIT : My solution :

t=480
n=10000

```
t1 = time.time()
for p in range(n):
    for j in range(M.shape[1]):
        M[j:j+t,j] = np.transpose(V[:])
print(time.time()-t1)
```

14 seconds for just 10 000 times... too long

EDIT 2 : benchmark of solution in the comment :

(Here Prate is V)

```
t1 = time.time()
for p in range(n):
    for j in range(M.shape[1]):
        M[j:j+t,j] = np.transpose(Prate[:])
print(time.time()-t1) 


t1 = time.time()
for p in range(n):
    n = len(Prate)
    m = np.tile(np.concatenate((np.array(Prate), np.zeros(t))), t)[:2*t*t-t]
    result = m.reshape(t, -1).T
print(time.time()-t1)  

t1 = time.time()
for p in range(n):
    ind = np.arange(t)
    indices = ((ind[:,None] + ind).ravel() , np.repeat(ind, t))
    base = np.zeros((n1, t))
    base[indices] = np.tile(Prate, t)
print(time.time()-t1)
```

**Output :**

```
16.737313747406006
29.46031618118286 
3.6843104362487793
```

**EDIT 3** : To avoid going through an array twice the size required, i ask my question differently :

I have a vector (1x6) :

```
V = [1 20 5 0  0  9]
```

And i want a matrix M (6x6) like this :

```
 [1.  20.  5.  0.  0.  9.]
 [0.  1.  20.  5.  0.  0.]
 [0.  0.  1.  20.  5.  0.]
 [0.  0.  0.  1.  20.  5.]
 [0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  20.]
 [0.  0.  0.  0.   0.  1.]
```

in each line it's the same vector V (a part of it) but with an offset to get a triangular matrix.

How can I Do that without loops ?

(that's just a simple example but the real vector V is way bigger)

Thank you :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want a fast solution and not a solution which avoids loops you can simply use `Numba` or `Cython`.

**Example**

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.njit()
def create_mat(V):
  arr=np.zeros((V.shape[0],V.shape[0]),dtype=V.dtype)
  for i in range(V.shape[0]):
    for j in range(i,V.shape[0]):
      arr[i,j]=V[j-i]
  return arr
```

**Timings**

```
V=np.random.rand(10000)
#The first call has an constant compilation overhead of about 0.2s, 
#which is neglected here.
create_mat: 0.35s
```

Comment: I didnt know that numba with njit was this fast compared to Python for loops ! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for an array `v`, we can first construct an numpy array with len(v)`extra`0`s:

```
n = len(V)
m = np.tile(np.concatenate((V, np.zeros(n))), n)[:2*n*n-n]
result = m.reshape(n, 1).T
```

For the given `V` list, this gives us:

```
>>> np.tile(np.concatenate((V, np.zeros(n))), n)[:2*n*n-n].reshape(n,-1).T
array([[10.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [20., 10.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [30., 20., 10.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [40., 30., 20., 10.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0., 40., 30., 20., 10.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0., 40., 30., 20., 10.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0., 40., 30., 20.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0., 40., 30.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0., 40.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

For a numpy array containing 500 elements, and 10'000 runs, we obtain:

```
>>> timeit(f, number=10000)
5.285840999999891
```

So converting a single array with 500 elements takes on my machine, 0.5 milliseconds. Constructing all these arrays will thus, approximately, take 52.86 seconds.

**EDIT**: I implemented the three attempts as follows:

```
def wil():
    n = len(V)
    return np.tile(np.concatenate((V, np.zeros(n))), n)[:2*n*n-n].reshape(n,-1).T


def mii():
    n = len(V)
    M = np.zeros((2*n-1, n))
    for j in range(n):
        M[j:j+n,j] = np.transpose(V[:])
    return M


def kas():
    n = len(V)
    ind = np.arange(n)
    indices = ((ind[:,None] + ind).ravel() , np.repeat(ind, n))
    base = np.zeros((2*n-1, n))
    base[indices] = np.tile(V, n)
    return base
```

and generated a random array with 500 elements:

```
V = np.random.randn(500)
```

then we ran tests with:

```
>>> timeit(wil, number=10000)
3.461620999999923
>>> timeit(mii, number=10000)
13.704932000000099
>>> timeit(kas, number=10000)
159.63497699999994
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for you answer. However, it takes more time as my solution...

Comment: @mii: well then it of course makes sense to share your solution.

Comment: Not faster but approximately the same i guess (i posted my solution)

Comment: @mii: if I run this with `timeit`, you approach results in 21.44 seconds locally.

Comment: I will check it on my computer ! I don't find those times for each method. Thank you !

Comment: @mii: when running your file locally, I get as benchmarks, `15.280482769012451`, `4.213433027267456`, and `2.1779391765594482`, strange...

Comment: If I however reorder the tests (with the test of Kasramvd first), Then I get `45.30609846115112 ` (kas...), `18.23612904548645` (original) and `4.804105997085571` (this).

Comment: Yeah calling funciton is way longer as direct code... I got the same time as you. Kasrâmvd method is faster 4 sec in direct code and 80 sec when i call function with timeit... 20x faster without def...

Comment: @miii: but even without `def`, there is a difference in timing if we just *reorder* the tests (so without the `def`). Typically calling a function takes some time, but is not *that* significant. It looks more that some methods have some "side-effects".

Answer (score 0):

Here is a vectorized approach:

```
In [74]: ind = np.arange(6)

In [75]: indices = ((ind[:,None] + ind).ravel() , np.repeat(ind, 6))

In [76]: base = np.zeros((11, 6))

In [77]: base[indices] = np.tile(V, 6)

In [78]: base
Out[78]: 
array([[10.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [20., 10.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [30., 20., 10.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [40., 30., 20., 10.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0., 40., 30., 20., 10.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0., 40., 30., 20., 10.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0., 40., 30., 20.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0., 40., 30.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0., 40.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for this solution. On my computer it's slower than the two previous... but good to learn some other way to do it !

Comment: @rniii How do you benchmar them? Please add your codes to the  question.

Comment: wrong method to time it, your method is faster if i didn't do it wrong (see EDIT 2) ! Great :D

Comment: but its odd because n=1000 is slower than n=10000 with my timeit... What do you think ?

Comment: @mii: I ran banchmarks, which actually indeed say that this method is (strangely enough) slower, but perhaps I implemented it the wrong way?

Comment: Your method is faster using direct code (without using "def")
4 sec for 10000 times
using "def" : 80 sec for the exact same code...

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
from scipy.linalg import toeplitz
res=np.tril(toeplitz(V).T
```

output:

```
res
>>array([[10, 20, 30, 40,  0,  1],
         [ 0, 10, 20, 30, 40,  0],
         [ 0,  0, 10, 20, 30, 40],
         [ 0,  0,  0, 10, 20, 30],
         [ 0,  0,  0,  0, 10, 20],
         [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 10]])
```