# shift numpy vector n times and create a matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm looking for a way to shift a `np.array` of length n, n-1 times and to create a matrix of the shifted vectors.

So for example if this is my vector:

```
[1,4,7,8]
```

What I want to get is:

```
[[None, None, None],
 [1   , None, None],
 [4   , 1   , None],
 [7   , 4   , 1   ]]
```

I can do it easily with a `for` loop and `shift`, but I was wondering whether there is a more efficient way with a builtin `numpy` function.

Comment: Is 8 supposed to be somewhere in the output array? Also, you can't have `None` in a numerical array. Is that supposed to be a list of lists rather than an actual numpy `ndarray`?

Comment: @bnaecker - 1. no, it shouldn't. the first column is shift(1), the second shift(2) etc.
2. you can have an np.nan in a numerical array if you convert it to float (astype(float)).

Comment: What is the `shift` function? Numpy has `np.roll`, if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: It is quite similar to this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/53169156/4045774

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one with `np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided` -

```
def shifted_subarrays(a, fill=None):
    a = np.asarray(a)
    fillar = np.full(len(a)-1, fill)
    a_ext = np.concatenate((fillar,a))
    n = len(a)
    s = a_ext.strides[0]
    strided = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided
    return strided(a_ext[len(a)-2:], shape=(n,n-1), strides=(s,-s))
```

Sample run -

```
In [20]: a = [1,4,7,8]

In [21]: shifted_subarrays(a)
Out[21]: 
array([[None, None, None],
       [1, None, None],
       [4, 1, None],
       [7, 4, 1]], dtype=object)

In [46]: shifted_subarrays(a, fill=np.nan)
Out[46]: 
array([[nan, nan, nan],
       [ 1., nan, nan],
       [ 4.,  1., nan],
       [ 7.,  4.,  1.]])
```

A simpler one with `toeplitz` -

```
from scipy.linalg import toeplitz
out = toeplitz(a,[None]*(len(a)))[:,1:]
```

Comment: @BinyaminEven See if the alternative one at the end makes you any *happier*. I sincerely hoped you were looking for performance efficiency and not code-golfing one.